# Issue with accuracy never changing ANN in kreas

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, data-science

I am trying to build simple ANN to learn how to tell if the two images are similar or not using two distance equations. So here how I set up things. I created a distance between 3 images (1, an anchor, 2 a positive sample, 3 a negative sample) and then created two different distance measurements. 1 using ResNet features and another using hog features. The two distance measurements are then saved with the two picture paths as well as the correct label (0/1) 0 = Same 1 = not the same.

Now I am trying to build out my ANN to learn the difference between the two values and see if this will allow for me to see if two images a similar. But nothing happens when I train up the ANN. I think there are two possibilities.

1: I didn't set up the ann correctly.

2: There is no connection at all.

Please help me see what the issue is:

Here is my code:

```
# Load the Pandas libraries with alias 'pd' 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
# fix random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(7)
import csv
data = pd.read_csv("encoding.csv")
print(data.columns)
X = data[['resnet', 'hog','label']]
x = X[['resnet', 'hog']]
y = X[['label']]

model = Sequential()
#get number of columns in training data
n_cols = x.shape[1]
#add model layers
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation= 'softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y, 
      epochs=30,
      batch_size=32,
     validation_split=0.10)
```

Right now all it does is this over and over again:

```
167/167 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 8.0189 - acc: 0.4970 - val_loss: 7.5517 - val_acc: 0.5263
```

Here is the csv file that I am using:

**EDIT**
So I have changed the setup a bit and now it does bounce up to 73% val accuracy. But then it bounces around and ends at 40% what does than mean?
Here is the new model:

```
model = Sequential()
#get number of columns in training data
n_cols = x.shape[1]
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1, activation= 'sigmoid'))

#sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
#model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = 'rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x, y, 
          epochs=100,
          batch_size=64,
         validation_split=0.10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to try :

- First add complexity to your network, it is pretty simple, add more layers/neurons in order to capture more information from your data
  Start with something like that, and see if it change something :

```py
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation= 'sigmoid'))
```

- Second, think to add more epochs, ANN can be long to converge

## Update

More things to try :

- Normalize and scale your data
- Maybe too small dataset -> the more data you get, the better your model will be
- Try differents hyper parameter, maybe decrease your learning rate like `1e-4` or `1e-5`, try differents batch_size, ..
- Add more regularization: try dropout between each layer

Comment: I did change the set up a bit, but now it bounces all over the place in accuracy and loss any ideas why that would happen?

Comment: I look through my data with a microscope and tried to find any relationship. I don't think there is any relationship at all. Thank for the suggestions,

Answer (score 3):

This makes no sense:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation= 'softmax'))
```

Softmax with one neuron will produce a constant value of 1.0 due to the normalization. For binary classification with the `binary_crossentropy` loss, you should use one neuron with `sigmoid` activation.

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation= 'sigmoid'))
```

Comment: That did change it but now it is stuck like this and won't change

Comment: loss: 8.0108 - acc: 0.5030 - val_loss: 8.4832 - val_acc: 0.4737